# How do I manage org and space users in bluemix using cf command line?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Bluemix provides a CF command line for download to manage applications.

We want to use CF (or any other command line tools ) to manage Organization and Space users. This will allow us to programmatically sync the user list.

Specifically I am looking for
    cf enroll-user 
    cf add-user  
    cf remove-user  
    cf unenroll-use

the cf command already lists the users for a given ORG and SPACE.

Comment: Are you asking this question because you got an access denied error? If so, you should document the error in your question's title, and should document what you did and the error you got in your question's text.

Comment: Bobby, I got access denied error message, then I looked for CF CLi documentation on Bluemix. Neither of those places solved my problem.
I knew I could list the users by org and then by space. 
My question was not to solve the error messages I got, but a commandline way of managing users (I am not married to CF implementation). I am more interested in automation in any tool.
It is unfortunate that the question was flagged with "-1".

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to read the docs. See "[Creating and Managing Users with the cf CLI](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/cli-user-management.html)." It documents commands like `create-user`, `set-org-role`, and `set-space-role`.

For example: Use `cf create-user USERNAME PASSWORD` to create a new user. The problem is, when you try to do this in Bluemix, you get an error:

```
>cf create-user jdoe password
Creating user jdoe as bwoolf...
FAILED
Error creating user jdoe.
Server error, status code: 403, error code: access_denied, message: Invalid token does not contain resource id (scim)
```

You get a similar error when you try to run `set-org-role` or `set-space-role`:

```
FAILED
Server error, status code: 403: Access is denied.  You do not have privileges to execute this command.
```

Why did you get this error? Like @RandalAnders explained, Bluemix currently blocks users from using these user administration commands in the CF CLI. For the time being, you'll need to perform these actions using the Bluemix Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Bobby, I posted the message after getting the access denied error.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is not possible within Bluemix to use the CF CLI for certain management commands, as they require administrative privileges. We are exploring expanding the scope of the commands used in the CLI and would be interested in hearing any other use cases you may have.

Comment: RandalAnders, We are using Bluemix to host production services. we want to track, report the users access to our production space. it would be great if this can be sync-ed with an LDAP/AD group. (If CLI or api is available, we can sync ourselves)
I also would love fine grained access like user X can only stop/start applications, user Y can deploy applications etc.,

Answer (score -1):

you can not create a user on bluemix using cf cli since it needs admin privileges. To add a user, you will need to use bluemix cli 'bluemix iam account-user-invite' to invite a user to your account with a org/space role assigned. There are other account/org/space/role management commands under 'bluemix iam'.

Download bluemix CLI here:  http://clis.ng.bluemix.net