# Bluemix CLI lists blank lines for org-users and space-users

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We're trying to audit access to our 3 orgs & 5 spaces across our development organisation on the public Bluemix eu-gb instance.  But, this is made tricky because we can't get a simple list.

We've tried `cf org-users` and `cf space-users`, but these return blank lines for each user.  Consequently, we've tried the `bx iam` versions of these commands, but they also return blank lines.

I have access to this information for the org in question (I can see it in the Bluemix dashboard), so this seems strange, as I'd expect the dedicated Bluemix CLI to send back the correct information.

`cf version 6.15.0+fa1bfe2-2016-01-13
bx version 0.3.0-4b6b71d-2016-02-19T09:07:14+00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bx iam space-users` now works in Bluemix CLI 0.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

`cf curl /v2/organizations`

and it will list (as JSON) an array of your organizations. Each one will contain a field like:

```
"users_url": "/v2/organizations/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd/users",
```

and if you then do `cf curl /v2/organizations/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd/users` it will output all the users who are members of that org.

Likewise you can use:

`cf curl /v2/spaces`

and this will give you separate links for users with the developer, manager, and auditor roles:

```
"developers_url": "/v2/spaces/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd/developers",
"managers_url": "/v2/spaces/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd/managers",
"auditors_url": "/v2/spaces/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd/auditors",
```

and you can then again use `cf curl` on those links to get the users.

Unfortunately it seems to only identify the users by GUID, not by any kind of human-readable string. I don't know if that's good enough for your purpose. It will at least allow you to see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a new version (0.3.2+), according to the [release notes](http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/all_versions.html) , 0.3.2 fixes that long existing issue.

> - Fix the defects in query org/space roles with interacting with Bluemix

Comment: Duplicate of my own answer below.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you might be bumping up against a (slightly different) instance of this problem:

> [How do I manage org and space users in bluemix using cf command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988664/how-do-i-manage-org-and-space-users-in-bluemix-using-cf-command-line)
>
> Currently, it is not possible within Bluemix to use the CF CLI for
>   certain management commands, as they require administrative
>   privileges. We are exploring expanding the scope of the commands used
>   in the CLI and would be interested in hearing any other use cases you
>   may have.

See also: [cf org-users and users name](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/191474/cf-org-users-and-users-name.html)

SUGGESTION:

Consider writing a short script with the Blumix REST Admin API:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/index.html#usingadminapi

Comment: Yeah.  Sadly the *bluemix-provided* CLI shows the same issue - this is the `bx iam` command set.  That's what this question is about.

Additionally, the Bluemix Admin API seems only to be valid for local & dedicated Bluemix instances.  I'll clarify the question to specify we're using the Bluemix public instance.